# picklist values turned to zero on case

Tags: picklist

I have a weird scenario.

I have a pickist field "priority" on case which has values in it.

But when i go to the records or try to create new records, i see the dropdown with all zeros.

Not sure what the issue is. Was working fine till yesterday.

And I could see two field labels on the layout as 0(zero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured the issue.
It was because of the translations.
Someone did it wrong to 0.